# Why does LibreOffice base, Microsoft Excel and Tableau require unnecessary permission to query table data from bigquery?

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, odbc, tableau-api, libreoffice-base

I have a BigQuery instance and I have shared a view with a service account. This service account has the "bigQuery.User" role. I setup Simba ODBC drivers on my Ubuntu machine, installed Libreoffice base on it and also modified the odbc.ini file to use the above service account. I'm able to connect to Bigquery but when I try to query the shared view, it throws an error saying that "user does not have BigQuery.tables.create permission for table ...". Looks like LibreOfficeBase Base is trying to create some temp tables. Tried with MS Excel and same error is thrown

My questions:

- Isn't the "bigQuery.User" role enough to query data from shared datasets/tables?
- Why does Libre Office Base require such extra permissions?

What I tried:

I shared the data with a user account(someuser@gmail.com). I gave the same role i.e. bigQuery.user to this account. I was able to query data successfully from this account.

I also tried on Tableau. Tableau has native support for Bigqyuery and also supports ODBC connections(to connect BigQuery, MySql, etc). I tried with both i.e. connecting to Bigquery using Tableau native BigQuery support and using ODBC connection. It worked with native BigQuery but not with ODBC connection(maybe it has the same issue as LibreOffice base and MS Excel)

Comment: Can you try to add roles/bigquery.dataEditor permission?

Comment: Why should it require even roles/bigquery.dataEditor  permission? It just needs to view the data